# How to execute recaptcha2 invisible? Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, recaptcha

I've been working in adding an invisible captcha in my site, and searching the best way to do it, I follow the instructions provided here: https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-captcha

I notice the instructions in the section "reCaptcha v2" does not explain how to trigger the validation over the captcha, so I'm blocked because I find that the captcha works well, however, as the captcha is an additional component in my login page, it should trigger once the user clicks on 'submit' button.

The problem I have, is that it seems there is a missing variable that let me execute the callback function in the captcha as it explains here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute
I see there is a variable (grecaptcha) with an 'execute()' function. So it takes into account the captcha validation.

At the moment, the code I have is following this structure:
HTML:
`

```
    <ngx-recaptcha2
    #captchaRef
    [siteKey]=captchaCode
    size="invisible"
    (resolved)="submitDataRC($event)"
    >
    </ngx-recaptcha2>

    <div>
         Form goes here...
         <button
         (click)="submitRecaptcha()"
         >Submit</button>
    </div>
```

`

TS
`

```
@ViewChild('captchaRef') captchaRef: any;
captchaCode = 'abc'
        
      submitRecaptcha() {
        console.log('start submit method')   // I notice the execution prints this message
        console.log(this.captchaRef)
        this.navDisable = true;
        // this.captchaRef.execute() // This method is commented because it appears an error: execute is not a function of captchaRef
    }


        submitDataRC(captchaResponse: string) {  // I hope the captcha call this method with the token inside here
                code of the method here...
        }
```

`

I hope I explain my properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still looking for this, I found the `execute()` method in the `grecaptcha` property. It's a private property (so it's not really clean to use it) but I didn't find any other way to execute it programatically.

So in your case it would be `this.captchaRef.grecaptcha.execute()`.

An other way would be to use ReCaptchaV3, which look easier to use in the typescript.

Hope it helps.